# Date parsed with gmt + 2 hours

Tags: javascript, date, date-parsing

I always get the wrong date when I use `var date = new Date(timestring)`, there is always +2 GMT hours.

```
var unsortedPlayTimes =
    [{date:'2014-08-11T09:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T08:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T08:15:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T08:45:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T12:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T10:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T11:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T07:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T13:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T23:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-12T00:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-12T01:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-12T05:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-12T09:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T14:00:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T18:30:00'},
        {date:'2014-08-11T13:00:00'}];

function SortandFilterPlayTimes (allPlayTimes) {
    var filteredPlayTimes = [];
    $.each(allPlayTimes, function(index, value) {
        var date = new Date(value.date);

        if ($.inArray(date,filteredPlayTimes) === -1) {
            filteredPlayTimes.push(date);
        }
    });
};
```

Why is JavaScript always adding this +2 hours ?

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: I think you are dealing with a timezone issue, can't give you a straight answer but here is a link giving one solution to use moment-timezone.js https://nulogy.com/articles/dealing-with-timezones-in-javascript#.U-y8pta1G2d

Answer (score 3):

You're using the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting of dates while omitting the timezone, [this makes the parsing consider the timezone as UTC in ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#ECMAScript_5_ISO-8601_format_support) (this will be different in ES6 : strings in ISO format will be considered as local too when the timezone isn't provided).

If you want the date to be parsed with your local timezone in ES5, you might change the format to a not ISO one :

```
var date = new Date(value.date.replace(/T/,' '));
```

But you might also want to check you really want the date to be parsed depending on the user's timezone, this is most often a bad idea. The usual good solution is to send the timezone or to send the date as a unix timestamp (what you get with `date.getTime()`).

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing ISO-8601 timestamps without timezone information, thus a UTC timezone is assumed, but `Date.prototype.toString()` will provide a string representation of this timestamp [**in your current timezone**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) which means that if you are in the UTC+2 timezone you will notice a shift by two hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your project is hosted on a server that has a +2 hours time difference with your local system, thus giving you a time you are not expecting. Is your server in a different country?