# fullcalendar angular5 moment substracts 2 hours from selected

Tags: angular, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

Working with [ap-angular2-fullcalendar package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ap-angular2-fullcalendar) (<-- [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/) )

Creating a new event at say 6AM - 8AM leads to moment saving it in DB as 4AM - 6AM

I console logged every part of the process:

That's the `start` select object:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Array(7), _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, 

_locale: Locale, …}
_a: (7) [2017, 10, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0]
_ambigTime: false
_ambigZone: true
_d: Wed Nov 08 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (שעון רגיל ירושלים) {}
_fullCalendar: true
_i: (7) [2017, 10, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0]
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"}
_offset: 0
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_z: null
__proto__: Object
```

That's the `end` select object:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Array(7), _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_a: (7) [2017, 10, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0]
_ambigTime: false
_ambigZone: true
_d: Wed Nov 08 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (שעון רגיל ירושלים) {}
_fullCalendar: true
_i: (7) [2017, 10, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0]
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"}
_offset: 0
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_z:null
__proto__: Object
```

From Response:

```
end: "2017-11-06T06:00:00.000Z"   // <--- 6AM
start: "2017-11-06T04:00:00.000Z" // <--- 4AM
```

The calendar component renders the event with the data as selected
But when I re-render the page - it shows the event with the times saved in DB, which are -2 hours then what I had selected

I read around - ["Date parsed with GMT+2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309434/date-parsed-with-gmt-2-hours) - I understand it is probably something linked to timezones, but could not link it to solving my own problem with this specific exercise

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Fixed by adding

`timezone: 'local'` to `calendarOptions`